# Where is the aneurysm in this picture?

Tags: hematology, neuroanatomy, circulatory-system, physiology

I'm a curious person, I've never had any medical training, but I wish to know some more about aneurysms. *Aneurysms* are basically weakened spots in the elastic artery wall. This can eventually result in a blood-filled balloon bulging from the artery wall due to the high blood pressure in these vessels. Aneurysms can rupture and this can lead to brain damage when it occurs in the brain. Aneurysms can be detected by injecting contrast material into the bloodstream and making an X-ray (called an *angiogram*). Now I was reading a wikipedia article about [**aneurysms**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aneurysm) where I saw the following picture of an angiogram where reportedly an aneurysm should be visble:

[image: aneurysm]

Now, as I said, I know nothing about biology so I would really appreciate it if someone could download the picture and reupload it with the aneurysm circled.

Is it the really dark spot or the big soft spot to the right? Thanks!

Comment: big blob just in the middle of picture

Comment: @aandreev Thanks so the black spot is normal?

Comment: I edited the question by adding some background info. this way other folks can more easily add answers if they wish.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your image comes from the wiki page [Aneurysm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aneurysm). The figure legend on the wiki page identifies it as:

> Angiography of an aneurysm in a cerebral artery

I am not an MD so I chose to first dig up a similar appearing cerebral angiography with the aneurysm identified (dark protruding spot indicated by the arrow):

[image: aneurysm]<sup>Source: [WestJEM, UC Irvine](http://westjem.com/articles/posterior-communicating-artery-aneurysm-in-20-year-old-female-with-noonans-syndrome.html)</sup>

Taking into account the normal vasculature as seen on this graph from UC Irvine, and given the similarity between the identified aneurysm in this angiopgraph and your wiki angiograph, I tentatively have identified the red-encircled structure in your original image as an aneurysm:

[image: wiki + identification]

Comment: Thanks! It looks like the one un the center of the wiki picture, as @aandrev said

Comment: Yes it does absolutely, but I found 'center' rather ambiguous

Comment: Exactly, that's why I asked for some circling or something haha, well, I guess my curiosity is satisfied, thanks!

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment, apparently, but I can answer that AliceD is correct. I'm a neuroradiologist, so I look at these images for a living.